# Self hosting nancy with razor returns empty body

Tags: c#, razor, owin, nancy

Self hosting nancy with razor returns empty body.

I'm trying to self-host nancy in a console application with razor views, however I'm getting an empty body back.
It does work when running in IIS.

What I did:

- I added all the appropriate razor configuration and build providers to the App.Config
- I added a custom static root path provider, which seems to be configured well, as static files are served without a problem:

  ```
  protected override IRootPathProvider RootPathProvider
  {
      get 
      {

          if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootPath"].HasValue())
          {
              var path = Path.Combine(new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Directory.FullName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootPath"]); 

              return new StaticRootPathProvider(path);
          }

          return new DefaultRootPathProvider();            
      }
  }
  ```
- The razor view is found an being compiled, because when I add invalid code to the view, I do get a razor compiler error
- When I debug with all exceptions caught, I get an exception on serving the page:

A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Nancy.dll

Additional information: Cannot convert type 'Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.Negotiator' to 'Nancy.Response'

> Nancy.dll!Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteInvoker.CastResultToResponse(dynamic result)    Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteInvoker.InvokeRouteWithStrategy(dynamic result, Nancy.NancyContext context) Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteInvoker.Invoke.AnonymousMethod__5(System.Threading.Tasks.Task completedTask)   Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.Helpers.TaskHelpers.WhenCompleted(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Action> onComplete, System.Action> onFaulted, bool execSync) Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteInvoker.Invoke(Nancy.Routing.Route route, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Nancy.DynamicDictionary parameters, Nancy.NancyContext context) Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher.Dispatch.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Threading.Tasks.Task completedTask) Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.Helpers.TaskHelpers.WhenCompleted(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Action> onComplete, System.Action> onFaulted, bool execSync) Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher.Dispatch(Nancy.NancyContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeRequestLifeCycle.AnonymousMethod__9(System.Threading.Tasks.Task t)    Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.Helpers.TaskHelpers.WhenCompleted(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Action> onComplete, System.Action> onFaulted, bool execSync) Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeRequestLifeCycle(Nancy.NancyContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)   Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.NancyEngine.HandleRequest(Nancy.Request request, System.Func preRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.NancyEngineExtensions.HandleRequest(Nancy.INancyEngine nancyEngine, Nancy.Request request, System.Func preRequest)   Unknown
>       Nancy.dll!Nancy.NancyEngineExtensions.HandleRequest(Nancy.INancyEngine nancyEngine, Nancy.Request request)  Unknown
>       Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll!Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.Process(System.Net.HttpListenerContext ctx) Unknown
>       Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll!Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.GotCallback(System.IAsyncResult ar) Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(System.IntPtr userToken) Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(object result, System.IntPtr userToken)   Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.IOCompleted(System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult asyncResult, uint errorCode, uint numBytes)    Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)  Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) Unknown

Then followed by a ArgumentNullException:

System.ArgumentNullException occurred
Message: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.dll
Additional information: Value cannot be null.

> System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext httpContext) Unknown
>       System.Web.Optimization.dll!System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Context.get()    Unknown
>       System.Web.Optimization.dll!System.Web.Optimization.Styles.RenderFormat(string tagFormat, string[] paths)   Unknown
>       Temp_bfd13a3e77214eca9b1ce8f1a37d244d.dll!RazorOutput.RazorView.Execute()   Unknown
>       Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll!Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase.ExecuteView(string body, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary sectionContents)  Unknown
>       [Lightweight Function]
>       Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll!Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.RenderView.AnonymousMethod__26(System.IO.Stream stream) Unknown
>       Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll!Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.OutputWithDefaultTransferEncoding(Nancy.Response nancyResponse, System.Net.HttpListenerResponse response)   Unknown
>       Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll!Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.ConvertNancyResponseToResponse(Nancy.Response nancyResponse, System.Net.HttpListenerResponse response)  Unknown
>       Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll!Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.Process(System.Net.HttpListenerContext ctx) Unknown
>       Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll!Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.GotCallback(System.IAsyncResult ar) Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(System.IntPtr userToken) Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(object result, System.IntPtr userToken)   Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.IOCompleted(System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult asyncResult, uint errorCode, uint numBytes)    Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)  Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) Unknown

UPDATE:

- That last stack trace seems to imply a problem with AspNet.Web.Optimization, perhaps related to this question:

[Can't get System.Web.Optimization to run with Nancy Self Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003482/cant-get-system-web-optimization-to-run-with-nancy-self-hosting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strip everything out of the view accept for a span tag.

```
<span>Hello</span>
```

Also I would strip everything out of the bootstrapper except the lines
needed for razor.

If this works then you know something else is tripping it up.

Comment: I switched to Cassette too. For some reason, I'm still getting first exception (Cannot convert type 'Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.Negotiator' to 'Nancy.Response') inside nancy when debugging, but it seems it's caught somewhere.

Comment: I dropped Cassette, having to many issues with it. Ended up building my own. https://github.com/donnyv/Nancy.BundleIt

Comment: Cool I will definitely have a look when I get the time. What kind of issues did you encounter with Cassette, it seems to work so far with us (but haven't moved it to production yet)?

Comment: I develop on windows and production runs on linux. I was getting a bunch of weird errors on linux. Also the performance wasn't great.